# What does profile means in an aac encoded audio

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg, aac, ffprobe

I am trying to concat two video files with `ffmpeg concat demuxer` for most of the part it works just fine!
But when I try to concat videos which has two different audio profile with same codec, it concats with the resulting video having weird sound problem. And when re-encoding the resulting video it will spit out a lots of error related to audio.

Here is ffprobe output for some audio stream from different video files
Video 1

```
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=4
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
...
[/STREAM]
```

Video 2

```
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=1
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
...
[/STREAM]
```

Video 3

```
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=28
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
...
[/STREAM]
```

Look the different `profile=` values.I was able to reproduce `28` and `1` but was failed for `4`

`28 = he_aac_v2` `1 = ffmpeg default`

So what I want to know the most is, 
What does these different values mean for aac? 
And how to reproduce them with any aac encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `libavcodec/avcodec.h`:

```
FF_PROFILE_AAC_MAIN    0
FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW     1
FF_PROFILE_AAC_SSR     2
FF_PROFILE_AAC_LTP     3
FF_PROFILE_AAC_HE      4
FF_PROFILE_AAC_HE_V2   28
FF_PROFILE_AAC_LD      22
FF_PROFILE_AAC_ELD     38
```

The native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`) does not have the ability to output HE or HEv2 profiles.

If you need HE profile (`-profile:a 4` or `-profile:a aac_he`) you'll have to use another encoder, such as `-c:a libfdk_aac`, `-c:a aac_at` (macOS/iOS only), or a separate standalone AAC encoder.

Comment: I see there are two MPEG2 entry
`
#define FF_PROFILE_MPEG2_AAC_LOW 128
#define FF_PROFILE_MPEG2_AAC_HE  131
`
What is the difference between 
`
FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW
FF_PROFILE_AAC_HE
`

Comment: @AnantaProdhan According to [FFmpeg AAC encoder documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Options-6) aac_low is *"The default, AAC 'Low-complexity' profile. Is the most compatible and produces decent quality."* It is the most common AAC profile found in typical files. HE is [High-Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding).